# App crashes when display button is clicked, no red code

Tags: button, crash, pressed

I'm trying to make a word mashing app (just as practice), and I got all the errors worked out in the code. When I go to run the app in the simulator, everything works but the "mash words" button. The app just crashes or freezes when it's clicked. I think I might have a problem with my outlet and action connections from the nib to the file's owner. Any feedback would help, thanks.

**Header File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Word_CombinerViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *word1;
    UITextField *word2;
    UITextField *display;
    UIButton *mashButton;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *word1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *word2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *display;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *mashButton;
-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;


@end
```

**Main File**

```
#import "Word_CombinerViewController.h"

@implementation Word_CombinerViewController
@synthesize word1;
@synthesize word2;
@synthesize display;
@synthesize mashButton;


-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
} 

-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [word1 resignFirstResponder];
    [word2 resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *newText = [word1.text stringByAppendingString:word2.text];
    display.text = newText;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [word1 release];
    [word2 release];
    [display release];
    [mashButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Also here is a screenshot of the connection from the button to the action in the files owner http://i551.photobucket.com/albums/ii448/ktmock/Screenshot2011-03-29at83131PM.png

If you need anything else lemme know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to put breakpoints in your buttonPressed method to know if it even makes it that far and on which line it'll break.

You might not have set up your referencing outlets. Control-click on File's Owner and drag the blue arrow to your different components and, in the popup window, select the object in your ViewController to link it to. For example, the button should link up to mashButton, one textfield to word1, another to word2, etc.

Comment: Ok, I connected "file's owner" to the appropriate objects in the nib (the first textField -> word1 Outlet, second textField -> word2 Outlet, and the button -> mashButton Outlet) However, there was no outlet to connect the display textField to, do I need one?

Comment: Yes, you need one. It should have been there looking at your property declarations. Is your display component a UITextField?

Comment: Yes the "display" textField is supposed to be my display component. Should I make an IBAction statement for the UITextField I want to use as my display? Sorry, i'm fairly new to this and i'm just trying to practice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, I ran it with breakpoints and it breaks at NSString *newText = [word1.text stringByAppendingString:word2.text];

Comment: You should create it if you're going to use it in your code. As for your app crashing at that line, it should be working correctly if you set up your view correctly in Interface Builder. The issue 'appears' to be that word1 and word2 don't seem to exist. Double check to see that it's working. You may also want to add NSLog(@"%@", word1); before that line so you can see what the value of word1 and whether it is a valid UITextField.

Comment: I figured it out, I had a UIScrollBox in the xib for the display. I replaced it with a UITextField and it works perfectly. Thanks!